# How to get variable values and use it on query Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm developing a query that needs to use a values that returned in this declaration:

```
DECLARE
    V_CD_AM NUMBER;

    cursor cd_am_cursor IS
       SELECT CD_AMOST
       FROM   L_CHEG
       WHERE  SQ_CHEG = 4153839;
BEGIN
    OPEN cd_am_cursor;
    LOOP
        FETCH cd_am_cursor into V_CD_AM;
        EXIT WHEN cd_am_cursor%NOTFOUND;                 
    END LOOP;
END;
```

This query above return two rows.
I want to get this two rows and run it on another query. The second query is more complex (there is some joins). Indeed all I need is result this second query.

```
SELECT AMAN.CD_AMOST_ANA CodAmAnalise,
             AN.DESCR_ANA         DescrAna,
             r.result              Result,
             ch.data_sist          DataCheg,
             AMAN.ORDEM               Ordem,
             aman.limite_atraso       LimiteAtraso,
             aman.idc_const       IdcConst,
             r.cod_obser         CodObser,
             r.tag_equip        Equip,
             SYSDATE                  DataAtual,
             r.seq_result          SeqResult,
             aman.cod_ana         CodAna,
             aman.idc_calc       IdcCalc,
             aman.cd_amost         CdAmost,
             aman.tempo_bloq      TempoBloq,
             r.data_sistema           DataSistema,
             r.idc_status             IdcStatus
        FROM AMOST_ANA AMAN
        JOIN ANALISE AN ON AMAN.CD_ANA = AN.CD_ANA
        LEFT JOIN CHEG_AMAN CHAMAN ON aman.cd_amost_ana =
                                                   chaman.cd_amost_ana
                                               AND aman.cd_amost =
                                                   chaman.cd_amost
                                               AND CHAMAN.seq_cheg =
                                                   4153839
        JOIN CHEG ch ON chaman.sq_cheg = ch.sq_cheg
                                 AND aman.cd_amost = ch.cd_amost
                                 AND ch.data_sistema =
                                     (SELECT MAX(data_sistema)
                                        FROM cheg
                                       WHERE sq_cheg = 4153839)
        JOIN RESULTADO R ON ch.SQ_CHEG = R.SQ_CHEG
                                  AND CHAMAN.CD_AMOST_ANA =
                                      R.COD_AMOST_ANA
                                  AND r.idc_status NOT IN ('T')
                                  AND (r.data_sistema =
                                      (SELECT MAX(data_sistema)
                                          FROM resultado
                                         WHERE sq_cheg = 4153839
                                           AND cd_amost_ana =
                                               CHAMAN.COD_AMOST_ANA
                                           AND idc_status NOT IN ('T')) OR
                                      r.data_sistema IS NULL)
       WHERE AN.IDC_ATIVO = 'True'
         AND aman.cd_amost = //Here in this line I would like use V_CD_AM
         AND AMAN.IDC_ATIVO = 'True'
       ORDER BY AMAN.ORDEM;
```

There is another way to execute this second query? The query works, if I put in:

`AND aman.cd_amost = someRealValue`

But this someRealValue must be dinamic, therefore I create the declaration `V_CD_AM`, How to get this values and run correctly this query?

Comment: Been a while since I did oracle, but why do you need a cursor?  You should be abel to just do your query directly in your larger query using an IN statement?  IF you are worried about performance you can insert your values into a temp/working table and do your IN statement on that

Comment: @Brad I do not necessarily need a cursor, but there is another way beyond temp table? Is there any solution to store the values in something like variables? And use it on second query? In some situations this values ID is identical. But the second query shows all informations.

Comment: If you just need to match on the amounts use a left join clause or in your where statement do where cd_amost  in (your select statement from your cursor here)

Comment: @Brad Thanks so much for your help. I believe that is more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Brad is saying is that you could do:

```
AND aman.cd_amost in (SELECT CD_AMOST FROM L_CHEG WHERE SQ_CHEG = 4153839)
```

or you could do it this way, and remove the line in the WHERE clause.

```
JOIN L_CHEG ON l_cheg.SQ_CHEG = 4153839
  AND aman.cd_amost = l_cheg.cd_amost
```

Comment: I was focused on making it the hardest way that I stoped thinking about the simpler. Thank you!